# How to fetch a query/mutation to graphene-django API from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, graphql

I am trying to make a mutation when the user submits a form, but I always get a 400 err.

The weird thing is that I used the GraphiQL interface to check how do they do the fetch function, and in the end, they use the exact same headers, method, body, and credentials. So I really don't know how to do it.

This is the mutation:

```js
  const comp_1 = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('comp-1')).value.trim();
  const comp_2 = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('comp-2')).value.trim();

  const mutation = `
    mutation CreateComps($comp1: String!, comp2: String!) {
      createCompetitors(comp1: $comp1, comp2: $comp2) {
        comp1 {
          id
          name
        }
        comp2 {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  fetch('/graphql/#', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      mutation,
      variables: { comp_1, comp_2 }
    }),
    credentials: 'include',
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(`${response.statusText} - ${response.url}`);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.stack === 'TypeError: Failed to fetch') {
      err = 'Hubo un error en el proceso, intenta más tarde.'
    }
    useModal('Error', err);
  })
```

And this is the GraphiQL function:

```js
function httpClient(graphQLParams, opts) {
  if (typeof opts === 'undefined') {
    opts = {};
  }
  var headers = opts.headers || {};
  headers['Accept'] = headers['Accept'] || 'application/json';
  headers['Content-Type'] = headers['Content-Type'] || 'application/json';
  if (csrftoken) {
    headers['X-CSRFToken'] = csrftoken
  }
  return fetch(fetchURL, {
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(graphQLParams),
    credentials: "include",
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (responseBody) {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(responseBody);
      } catch (error) {
        return responseBody;
      }
    });
}
```

I get a 400 error that just says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`, and the Django output says:

```
Bad Request: /graphql/
[07/Feb/2021 12:51:44] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 400 294
```

But that is not it. After this, I tried to use an npm package called `grapql-request` ([link](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request)), and I don't know if the code is right because I get errors in the importing, no matter what I do.

You have to import two things, which I do like this: `import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request"` (like the docs said to), and then in the browser console I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "graphql-request". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"..`

The node_modules dir is below the project's dir, so it is at the highest level. I try to import like this: `import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "../../../../node_modules/graphql-request"`, and get this error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/graphql-request net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).`

I thought that if I moved this to the static dir of the app, it could work, so I tried it, importing like this: `import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "../../node_modules/graphql-request"`, and importing in the html file like this: `<script src="{% static 'node_modules/graphql-request' %}" type="module"></script>`, and now I still get the same error from before: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/node_modules/graphql-request net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

So I really don't know what to do. If anyone could help me, I would be very pleased, since I am having problems fetching to GraphQL API since Thursday, and I am really close to redoing the app but with `django-rest-framework`

BTW this is the URL I am using:

```py
path('graphql/', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=False))
```

Comment: variables should be used, both in graphiql and code ... **no query string manipulations!** ... show this *'exact same headers/body'*

Comment: what do you mean with graphql and code? I will update the question @xadm

Comment: So I understand what you were saying about variables, and I edited *my* mutation. Check it out @xadm

Comment: show/compare RAW NETWORK request headers/bodies from `/grqphiql` ('query variables' should be used) and your code

Comment: I am now using the query variables @xadm . Do you want me to put the complete graphiql file in the question? I also put the graphql url

Comment: I don't care files... show/compare NETWORK requests (headers+bodies) from both *'the same'* looking (and using variables) `/graphiql` and `fetch`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228386/discussion-between-joaquin-and-xadm).

Answer (score 0):

You have a sintax error in the query: `$comp1: String!, comp2: String!`. You have to add the `$` before `comp2`.

In the `body`, do it like this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ 
      query: mutation,
      variables: { comp1: comp_1, comp2: comp_2 }
    })
```

Before, the body was like this:

```
{
    mutation: <the mutation>,
    variables: {
        comp_1: <comp_1>,
        comp_2: <comp_2>
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that there is no query, and graphql needs one, and also there is no variable in the query named `comp_1`, there is one called `comp1`, and the same for `comp_2`.

And add: `credentials: 'include'`